# Adding SQL indices

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-express

I'm currently working on a SQL assignment that wants me to:
**Add an index for each foreign key and an index on Company for Customer and Shipper.**

I've created the 3 tables that were needed, created the foreign and primary keys, and so on. But my textbook has not mentioned anything about indices and I am at a loss as to what to do. If you have an answer, it'd be nice to know how you got to it.

The structure of the tables:

**Customer**

```
CustomerID (PK) | Company   | ContactName  | Phone
```

**Order**

```
OrderID (PK)    | OrderDate | ShippedDate  | ShipperID  | Freight  | CustomerID (FK)
```

**Shipper**

```
ShipperID (PK)  | Company   | Phone
```

Comment: Check your database manual for the `CREATE INDEX` statement.

Comment: huh? @FerretallicA I did the edit on the question above, yet it says you did it. Also looking at the revision of the question - my edits are listed under your name... :| Is this a bug or am I going crazy?

Comment: As a student, you should be solving/resolving this yourself.  BOL (Books OnLine) is your friend.  It is not "proper form" for us to help you.  Sorry, if I seem a bit unfriendly, but I think your teacher/prof will agree.  :)

Comment: Whoa. Thanks for the honesty, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at the [online documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx), but...

To create indexes for foreign keys:

```
create index Order_ShipperID on Order(ShipperID);
create index Order_CustomerID on Order(CustomerID);
```

To create indexes on Company for Customer and Shipper:

```
create index Customer_Company on Customer(Company);
create index Shipper_Company on Shipper(Company);
```

The names of the indexes can be anything, but I usually follow this naming convention.

---

BTW, the choice of name "Order" is a poor one because its a reserved word.

Comment: If the schema had specified that CustomerID, OrderID and ShipperID  are unique - is that the same as explicitly creating an index? Also do you need to reindex a table after adding new entries?

Comment: If id columns are defined as `primary key` they implicitly have a unique index defined over them. If you have not defined them as primary keys, you should cradle a unique index - just add the word `unique` between "create" and "index". You do not need to reindex are adding data - the database maintains the index on the fly

Comment: I see. In this case - given that those fields are already primary keys (according to the OP's description of the tables) - isn't `create index` superfluous?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Index on any SQL Table column. Once Indexes are created on your Table column you just have to send  the Select query and you can check logically the performance of you query. You can check the next link for reference to the solution:

www.blog.mastersoftwaresolutions.com/how-do-database-indexes-work/